# Converting icon to png file on a web server C#

Tags: generics, bitmap, icons, png, gdi+

I am trying to convert an icon to png on a web server with the following code. But I always get the "GDI+ generic error", when saving the bitmap. What am I missing?

```
private static byte[] IconAsSizedPng(byte[] iconBytes, int iSize)
    {
        System.Drawing.Icon icon;
        using(var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(iconBytes))
            icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(ms, iSize, iSize);
        using(icon) {
            using(var bmp = icon.ToBitmap()) {
                //bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                using(var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Byte data is:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the Identity of AppPoolUser to "LocalSystems". Now it works. Seems like it is somehow a "permission" problem.